# Wired network issues (disabled ethernet)

Tags: networking, 13.10, ethernet

I am brand new to linux, having downloaded it yesterday. I am booting off of a 16g USB drive, running Ubuntu 13.10.

My problem is that I cannot connect to the wired Ethernet, at all. My computer can connect to the internet when booted off of either local hard drive (Windows Vista and XP, one on each drive), so this is not a hardware issue. But whenever I tried to boot off of my USB drive on Ubuntu, I cannot connect to the internet.

The network manager in the top right corner has the Ethernet greyed out, and the line below that says "disabled" - I'm not sure if that line refers to the Ethernet or to the Wifi (which my computer does not have).

I don't know what I need to do to fix this. Could someone help me through it? I know I'm probably going to edit in some outputs, but I don't know what commands to run.

According to Windows, I am using:
`Intel(R) PRO/100 VE Network Connection`
and `6TO4 Adapter`. The `6TO4 Adapter` is failing to start, but I am posting this from the same computer.

Comment: What is your computer hardware? It may be that your network adapter isn't supported, but if we don't know what it is we can't help you.

Comment: Let me reboot into vista and I'll get back to you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem originated from my network adapter. The adapter is failing, and only works under Vista, not under XP or Ubuntu.

With the hardware failing, it's time to get a new adapter. No software fixes will work for this.

Comment: "adapter is failing, and only works under Vista" this is a contradiction and hence more likely a driver issue.

Answer (score 3):

stop network-manager

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Then :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

Then :

start network manager

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

Comment: While this is no doubt a way to solve the issue, and has worked for friends of mine, this did not fix my issue.

Comment: Have been having DNS lookup issues for a day. Executing sudo was also slow because of this. Finally, these instructions fixed all my issues.

Comment: not working in my case