# Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS couldn't recognize ethernet internet as well as graphics issue

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I had this [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243328/dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu-linux-18-04-lts-upgrade-to-20-04lts-kernel-5-4-is) in the past. After the BIOS update, 20.04LTS is loading up(though slowly)-but no internet connection(even when i am using Ethernet cable and it works fine in Windows 10-so no hardware issue). Graphics driver is also not loaded. Yes, I am talking about multiple issues but i want to focus only on networking right now.
I cannot login to 18.04 LTS strangely.

Tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414602/wired-network-issues-disabled-ethernet) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243500/linux-ubuntu-server-20-04-lts-network-unreachable) but no luck

Output of `ip a` or `ifconfig`
[image]

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`
[image]

Output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`
[image]

Dell XPS 8930. NVidia GEFORCE GTX 1060

**Update1**

Finally I got fed up of login into ubuntu linux - try out one command after the other, take the snapshot from phone and then post it here to go no where.
Decided to install Ubuntu Linux all over again.
Install detected 20.4 LTS already and gave me the option to install 20.4.1 LTS along side it. Tried that option but it also messed up. Was getting the black grub 2 screen and nothing else.
Tried boot-repair from live USB and it's back.

Better to always install fresh rather than upgrade or rely on others suggestions.

Comment: Please add the output of `ip a` or `ifconfig`

Comment: Re-install is easy when it's a brand new system and there is no apps or data. If i can fix the internet issue - I might be able to conquer other issues also.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Done-provided all the command output

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer or motherboard. Tell me what make/model video card, and video driver version. What processor? Is Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema - provided the inputs Dell XPS 8930. NVidia GEFORCE GTX 106. Secure boot is disabled. This computer i ran 18.04 LTS for years without any issue

Comment: Your BIOS is current. You didn't say what version Nvidia driver. What processor? Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the ethernet works. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema - 940 or 960 and it was working fine with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: What is "940 or 960"? The current Nvidia driver for your GTX 1060 is 450.57.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111865/discussion-between-ashu-and-heynnema).